# Loading data array into datatables using ajax

Tags: ajax, datatables

I am trying to load following array into datatables,

```
  var array=  {
        "rowNumber": 2,
        "mailingID": 3,
        "firstname": "Bruce",
        "lastname": "Ballister",
        "organization": "Apalachee Regional Planning Council",
        "address1": "20776 Central Avenue East",
        "address2": "Suite 1",
        "city": "Blountstown",
        "state": "FL",
        "zip": 32424
      }
```

But, the table is not loading the array into datatable. Also, i can see the array has been received into browser's "response" tab. I think I am missing something in it.

My code:

```
$.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "getLabels.jsp",
            data : "mailingID=" + selectedValue, // posCodeSelected
            success : function(data) {
             var array= data;
             $(document).ready(function() {
                    $('#printIDs').dataTable( {
                        "ajax": array, /* i think change is needed here*/
                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "rowNumber" },
                            { "data": "mailingID" },
                            { "data": "firstname" },
                            { "data": "lastname" },
                            { "data": "organization" },
                            { "data": "address1" },
                            { "data": "address2" },
                            { "data": "address3" },
                            { "data": "address4" },
                            { "data": "city" },
                            { "data": "state" },
                            { "data": "zip" }

                        ]
                    } );
                } );

            },
            error : function(response) {
                var responseTextObject = jQuery
                        .parseJSON(response.responseText);
            }
        });
```

Fiddle link : http://jsfiddle.net/kpqru5hm/

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle for your code

Comment: I don't think you need to use `$(document).ready(function() {}` in the success function.

Comment: @HarshulPandav: inserted fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

The structure of the array you have used seems to be incorrect for the datatables.

Your code should be like :

**HTML**

```
<table id="printIDs" class="table">

</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var dataSet = [
    ['Misc','IE Mobile','Windows Mobile 6','-','C'],
    ['Misc','PSP browser','PSP','-','C'],
    ['Other browsers','All others','-','-','U']
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "data": dataSet,
        "columns": [
            { "title": "Engine" },
            { "title": "Browser" },
            { "title": "Platform" },
            { "title": "Version", "class": "center" },
            { "title": "Grade", "class": "center" }
        ]
    } );   
} );
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/harshulpandav/kpqru5hm/2/

For more info: http://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html

Comment: Make sure you have added the required CDN i.e. JS and CSS files in order to use the Bootstrap Datatables