# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&' in DataTable using Symfony2

Tags: jquery, symfony, datatables

I need to append response in `datatable`

**Symfony code:**

```
 public function ListUsersDataAction() {
    $result = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $person_data = $result->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u.id,u.email, u.phone_number,u.buy_min,u.buy_max,u.sell_min,u.sell_max,u.status,u.start_date,u.end_date')
            ->from('AcmeBitcoinBundle:AlertData', 'u')
            ->orderBy('u.id', 'asc')
    ;
    //$sql=$results->getQuery();
    //echo   $sql->getSql();
    $data = $person_data->getQuery()->getResult();
    $json = '[';
    $first = 0;
    foreach ($data as $v) {
        if ($first++)
            $json .= ',';
        $json .= '["' . $v['id'] . '",
    "' . $v['email'] . '",

    "' . $v['phone_number'] . '"]';
    }
    $json .= ']';

    return $this->render('AcmeBitcoinBundle:Datatable:list.html.twig', array(
                'json_data' => $json
    ));
}
```

**JSON response:**

```
[
  [ "3","***@gmail.com","***"],
  ["4","**@gmail.com","43534654"]
]
```

**twig file:**

```
   var dataSet={{json_data}}
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
       "data": dataSet,
       "columns": [
          { "title": "Engine" },
          { "title": "Browser" },
          { "title": "Platform" }

        ]
       } );   
      } );
   </script>
```

**References:**

- I tried [Loading data array into datatables using ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27383894/loading-data-array-into-datatables-using-ajax)
- https://www.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html
- It's accepting:

  `var dataSet = [
  ['Misc','IE Mobile','Windows Mobile 6','-','C'],
  ['Misc','PSP browser','PSP','-','C'],
  ['Other browsers','All others','-','-','U']
  ];`
- i look into viewsource

  ```
     <script>
       var dataSet=[[&quot;3&quot;,
        &quot;hhh@gmail.com&quot;,

     &quot;24354&quot;],[&quot;4&quot;,
     &quot;25435@gmail.com&quot;,

     &quot;43534654&quot;]]
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
  "data": dataSet,
     "columns": [
      { "title": "Engine" },
      { "title": "Browser" },
      { "title": "Platform" }

  ]
    } );
  ```

  } );
- solution  i tried

  ```
      var dataSet=    {{ json_data|json_encode() }}
  ```
- any suggestion is most welcome

  update twig code

  ```
   <table id="example" class="table">

  </table>
  ```

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
     "data": {{ json_data|raw }},
     "columns": [
       { "title": "Id" },
        { "title": "Email" },
        { "title": "Phone Number" }

      ]
  } );
  ```

  } );

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `|raw` in your twig json variable, like `var dataSet={{ json_data|raw }}`

This will not escape output. https://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/filters/raw.html